# Save angular component as html

Tags: angular, laravel, typescript

I have an angular(5) registration form. When you finish, it generates an invoice. Everything is done using angular and of course it talks with API to save data to the back (using laravel).

I want to send an email also with the invoice. Of course it's a bad idea to code again the invoice in PHP as it's code duplication and in different languages. Maintaining this would be a nightmare, as it's duplication.

I want to get what angular is showing as invoice as it is and send it as mail or save it as .html file.

What i've tried so far:

```
const elementToSave = document.getElementById('receiptInner').innerHTML;
```

I've put this ngAfterViewInit(). If i get the html angular generates than i can post it and save it as html or send it as email. But is it safe, i'm concerned of sending so big data of HTML for security reasons, on the other hand duplication of cose in php doesnt sound correct.

What is the prefered way ?

How can i simply do what i'm trying ?